# Re-priming over sanded primer

Tags: painting

I’m finishing bare oak cabinets. I burned through the coat of primer during my sanding. Am I good to start spraying the alkyd paint on this or do I need to go back a prime again over the burned through areas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you need to re-prime.

That's why care while sanding is a good idea, and that's also why it's very common to prime 2 or more coats.  Honestly it's almost inevitable to blow through the first coat on sanding; this is just you exposing the high spots.

Leveling is one goal of priming; you're using the primer essentially as a filler to fill the low spots.

As you get the surface more the way you want, switch to finer sandpaper and less pressure.

Answer (score 0):

If the final appearance is critical, you should reprime. The finish coat, especially if it has significant gloss, may look different in those areas where you burned through.

If perfection is not important and/or your finish coat is not glossy, don't worry about it.